# log4j error mails hanging threads

Tags: java, multithreading, email, log4j

We had some issues where our production environment answers extremly slow to requests and discovered that Tomcat had run out of worker threads. This was partly our fault due to an old feature that hogged threads, but we also found something interesting regarding log4j and mailing error logs. There was a single log4j error logging thread trying to send a mail that was blocking 34 other threads. The thread dump from the blocking thread looked like this:

```
"http-apr-80-exec-777" - Thread t@4195
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:97)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    - locked <45b6408b> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:75)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1440)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1260)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender.sendBuffer(SMTPAppender.java:416)
    at org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender.append(SMTPAppender.java:256)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    - locked <54ebd98f> (a org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    - locked <731a1e23> (a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.error(Category.java:305)
    at org.apache.jsp.errorpage_jsp._jspService(errorpage_jsp.java:197)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    - locked <6af9560> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <7a82445e> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

While the 34 blocked threads looked typically like this:

```
"http-apr-80-exec-787" - Thread t@4306
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:204)
    - waiting to lock <731a1e23> (a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger) owned by "http-apr-80-exec-777" t@4195
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.error(Category.java:305)
    at org.apache.jsp.errorpage_jsp._jspService(errorpage_jsp.java:197)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    - locked <2d079e0c> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <7dac19bb> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

What could cause this? Problems with the mail server? Is there any configuration in log4j that could prevent or reduce the consequences of the locks?

Server running on Tomcat 7 on windows server 2008 using log4j 1.2.17, javax.mail 1.4

Comment: Possible cause : https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50213 Possible solution : http://troyjsd.blogspot.sg/2009/07/user-complaints-of-slow-j2ee-pages.html

Comment: Interesting, I'll check it out

Comment: @Pushkar if you add your comment as an answer, ill mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out this bug in the Apache Log4j regarding thread blocking in the Logger : https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50213

This should not be an issue in most cases, but if we are using something like a SMTPAppender which can take some time to execute then this may cause problems.

A possible solution is to use a Async Logger

```
<appender name="asyncAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
  <appender-ref ref="theTargetAppender"/>
  <param name="BufferSize" value="512" />
  <param name="Blocking" value="false" />
 </appender>
```

One thing to remember is that since its async if your program crashes before the async thread logs then that log message may get lost.

**More Info :** http://troyjsd.blogspot.sg/2009/07/user-complaints-of-slow-j2ee-pages.html

Comment: I don't think it was a deadlock due to a bug but rather the (seemingly) intended issue of loggers being synchronized combined with temporary issues on our mail server, causing all loggers threads to wait for one that was timing out eventually. Regardless, the async logger seems almost like a requirement to make use of the SMTP appender, and would solve our problems if it happens again.